# Read and modify Images in Python

Tags: python

Hi I want to change images from color to gray scales, rename and save the gray scale images to another folder

At the moment I saved color images' file names into a list then use for loop to go through them.

```
import os
from PIL import Image 
color_images = []
color_images = os.listdir(r'D:\myfolder\data\color') 

for imagefile in color_images :
    im=Image.open(imagefile)
    gray = im.convert('1')
    gray.save('/gray')
```

My questions are:

1. I received error message on this line `im=Image.open(imagefile)` error:  `No such file or directory: '001.jpg'` but the image is in the folder
2. how to rename the images with for loop (eg: image 001.jpg will become 001_gray.jpg) and save them in the folder I want (D:\myfolder\data\gray).

Thanks!

Comment: probably you need to give the full path to the image, not the relative path. i.e. '/home/user/pictures/001.jpg' or something. Alternatively you run python from the same folder the images are in, or you change the path using the `os` package

Comment: You have `imagefile` and `image_file` in the code and no line `im=Image.open(imagefile)`. Try to simply copy and paste the code (properly formatted) into the question from the source file.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from PIL import Image

#Path to the folder, myfolder\data\gray is in same folder of .py?
DIR = os.getcwd() + '\\myfolder\\data\\color'
DIR2 = os.getcwd()+'\\gray'

#list of images
color_images = os.listdir(DIR)

for imagefile in color_images:
    im=Image.open(imagefile)
    gray = im.convert(DIR2)
    gray.save(DIRGRAY)

c = 1
for i in os.listdir(DIR2):
    os.rename(i, str(c)+'.jpg')
    c+=1
```

Comment: Thank you. `myfolder\data\gray` is not in the same folder as .py, .py is at the same layer as \data\   I still receive error message `No such file or directory: '001.jpg'` at this line`im=Image.open(imagefile)`